# Creating instances of classes python & __init__

Tags: python, oop, class

I want a class that has some class variables, and has functions that perform stuff on those variables - but I want the functions to be called automatically. Is there a better way to do it? Should I be using **init** for this? Sorry if this is a nooby question - I am quite new to Python.

```
# used in second part of my question
counter = 0    

class myClass:
    foo1 = []
    foo2 = []

    def bar1(self, counter):
        self.foo1.append(counter)
    def bar2(self):
        self.foo2.append("B")

def start():
    # create an instance of the class
    obj = myClass()
    # I want the class methods to be called automatically...
    obj.bar1()
    obj.bar2()

# now what I am trying to do here is create many instances of my class, the problem is
# not that the instances are not created, but all instances have the same values in 
# foo1 (the counter in this case should be getting incremented and then added
while(counter < 5):
    start()
    counter += 1
```

So  is there a better way to do this? And is causing all of my objects to have the same values? Thanks!

Comment: foo1 and foo2 are class variables, they are shared by all the objects,, if you want them to be separate for all the objects, create `__init__` method and initialize them in the function

Comment: Thanks - edited that. So if they are in `__init__` , and I create obj1, then create obj2, both will have variables set to whatever  is in the `__init__`, where as if they are in just the class definition, obj1.doSomething() changes the variables that obj2 will use? (assuming doSomething() changes a class variable)

Comment: -- note: this is answered below: see @avasal

Answer (score 4):

foo1 and foo2 are class variables, they are shared by all the objects,

your class should look like this, if you want `foo1`, `foo2` to be different for every object:

```
class myClass:
    # __init__ function will initialize `foo1 & foo2` for every object
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo1 = []
        self.foo2 = []

    def bar1(self, counter):
        self.foo1.append(counter)
    def bar2(self):
        self.foo2.append("B")
```

Comment: Thank you very much - clears up my confusion about the `__init__` method.